# Managed heap in CLR

Tags: c#, memory-management, .net-4.0, clr

I read about CLR in .NET as:

When CLR loads heap is partitioned in SOH and LOH.

1. when application is started at that time heap is allocated by CLR to application depending on its size.
2. LOH heap has Gen0,Gen1,and Gen2 regions.

Here all objects for A class are allocated on Gen0,

**Questions**

1. How CLR knows the size will occupied by application in heap?
2. Suppose there is 4K heap memory allocated by CLR for **Gen0** region. Given the code below, is it possible for this single thread to use full 4K memory on Gen0?

   ```
   collect = new List();
   while(true)
   {
       collect.Add(new A());
       new A();
       new A();
   }

   class A
   {
       int a = 0, b = 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: 1. I believe this is done by calculating a size of all declared fields surely considering its types

Comment: that is this is the way to allocate needed memory on heap at start of application.What about second question?

Comment: I think CLR will looks the metadata of assembly from that can it calculates the needed heap.Am i correct?

Comment: The LOH is not generational. It uses a free list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I believe this is done by calculating a size of all declared fields surely considering its types. For more detaikls see MSDN ["Allocating Memory"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t.aspx)
2. Regarding MSDN paper ["Automatic Memory Management"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t.aspx) all new objects (as [Brian Rasmussen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38206/brian-rasmussen) noted in comments below - generations are applicable for SOH only, large objects created in LOH is not generational healp) initially created in `Gen0` and only those which survives while application's life will be moved to `Gen1`. But it is mentioned that in case when `Gen0` is full - GC performs garbage collection to clean up `Gen0` and if it is still full - all new objects will be created in `Gen1`.

Comment: thanks,I read link .It clear much,but one problem.Here in while loop we allocates the object on heap so how CLR nows in advanced to how many objects while loop will create.

Comment: Is  CLR can increase the size of allocated heap for application dynamically .

Comment: Not all objects are allocated in Gen0. Objects larger than 85000 bytes are allocated on the large object heap.

Comment: But this would be LOH rather than SOH? I suppose eash heap has own Gen0,Gen1... am I wrong?

Comment: There are two logical heaps. The generational heap which covers Gen0 to Gen2 and the LOH. The LOH is handled very differently from the generational heap. It doesn't use generations, it's not compacted and it uses a free list similar to a crt heap.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out. I've put your notes in answer if you do not mind